# Keep and label rows after joining dplyr

Tags: r

I have two dataframe which I want to join normally i do `inner_join` which gives only the one which are present in both dataframe and rest and not shown in my output.

How to do innerjoin and keep all the rows and assign label

First dataframe

```
dput(head(EF_TF_region_expression))
structure(list(ENSEMBL = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("ENSG00000006468", 
"ENSG00000030419", "ENSG00000057657", "ENSG00000068305", "ENSG00000068903", 
"ENSG00000082014", "ENSG00000085276", "ENSG00000091831", "ENSG00000100298", 
"ENSG00000102349", "ENSG00000102554", "ENSG00000102935", "ENSG00000105991", 
"ENSG00000107485", "ENSG00000109906", "ENSG00000112182", "ENSG00000118922", 
"ENSG00000119508", "ENSG00000121067", "ENSG00000124203", "ENSG00000124440", 
"ENSG00000124613", "ENSG00000130382", "ENSG00000136770", "ENSG00000138738", 
"ENSG00000140009", "ENSG00000140968", "ENSG00000143499", "ENSG00000146285", 
"ENSG00000146592", "ENSG00000147862", "ENSG00000148143", "ENSG00000150907", 
"ENSG00000151090", "ENSG00000151322", "ENSG00000151623", "ENSG00000152217", 
"ENSG00000159882", "ENSG00000160321", "ENSG00000162367", "ENSG00000162599", 
"ENSG00000162772", "ENSG00000164105", "ENSG00000164684", "ENSG00000167034", 
"ENSG00000167081", "ENSG00000171316", "ENSG00000173258", "ENSG00000174306", 
"ENSG00000176399", "ENSG00000176842", "ENSG00000177508", "ENSG00000177606", 
"ENSG00000177946", "ENSG00000178028", "ENSG00000178175", "ENSG00000178187", 
"ENSG00000178573", "ENSG00000181690", "ENSG00000182348", "ENSG00000185155", 
"ENSG00000185420", "ENSG00000185630", "ENSG00000186350", "ENSG00000186766", 
"ENSG00000187098", "ENSG00000189190", "ENSG00000196498", "ENSG00000197343", 
"ENSG00000197576", "ENSG00000198300", "ENSG00000213341", "ENSG00000213793", 
"ENSG00000213973", "ENSG00000269067"), class = "factor"), Symbol = structure(c(13L, 
20L, 45L, 45L, 30L, 51L), .Label = c("APOBEC3H", "ATF3", "BACH2", 
"CENPBD1", "CHD7", "CHUK", "CREB5", "DMAP1", "DMRTA1", "DNAJC1", 
"ESR1", "ESR2", "ETV1", "FOXI2", "FOXO1", "GATA3", "HIF3A", "HOXA1", 
"HOXA4", "IKZF2", "IRF8", "IRX3", "IRX5", "JUN", "KLF12", "KLF5", 
"KLF8", "MAF", "MECOM", "MEF2A", "MITF", "MIXL1", "MLLT1", "NCOR2", 
"NFIA", "NFIB", "NKX3-1", "NPAS3", "NR3C2", "NR4A3", "PBX1", 
"PBX3", "PEG3", "PLAG1", "PRDM1", "PRDM5", "RXRA", "SAP30", "SCML4", 
"SETBP1", "SIRT2", "SMARCD3", "SMYD2", "SMYD3", "SPOP", "TAL1", 
"THRB", "ZBTB16", "ZHX3", "ZNF208", "ZNF230", "ZNF366", "ZNF391", 
"ZNF423", "ZNF454", "ZNF462", "ZNF483", "ZNF600", "ZNF655", "ZNF704", 
"ZNF728", "ZNF804B", "ZNF831", "ZNF888", "ZNF99"), class = "factor"), 
    gene = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("gene_down", 
    "gene_UP"), class = "factor"), Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Region_down", "Region_UP"), class = "factor"), 
    log2FoldChange_gene = c(-6.14406801102623, -2.6627775459419, 
    3.88870894117496, 3.88870894117496, 1.99677979125181, -1.97211419094463
    ), Peak_Region = structure(c(22L, 1L, 19L, 19L, 57L, 70L), .Label = c("Peak116875", 
    "Peak122965", "Peak124509", "Peak12882", "Peak129965", "Peak133291", 
    "Peak137285", "Peak144690", "Peak156227", "Peak158090", "Peak159944", 
    "Peak165589", "Peak17226", "Peak17361", "Peak174329", "Peak177429", 
    "Peak182129", "Peak18278", "Peak182835", "Peak183059", "Peak187290", 
    "Peak190384", "Peak191607", "Peak191615", "Peak191784", "Peak196275", 
    "Peak197134", "Peak20062", "Peak201433", "Peak204083", "Peak206496", 
    "Peak206939", "Peak208441", "Peak21185", "Peak215070", "Peak215745", 
    "Peak219884", "Peak220299", "Peak220725", "Peak221948", "Peak222959", 
    "Peak22385", "Peak226499", "Peak28743", "Peak30996", "Peak40815", 
    "Peak4292", "Peak4601", "Peak53449", "Peak5453", "Peak56079", 
    "Peak5702", "Peak58241", "Peak58295", "Peak62243", "Peak64400", 
    "Peak74210", "Peak77556", "Peak77907", "Peak77943", "Peak79841", 
    "Peak80519", "Peak81090", "Peak85355", "Peak91665", "Peak95258", 
    "Peak96987", "Peak97000", "Peak97004", "Peak97803", "Peak98350", 
    "Peak98598", "Peak99349", "Peak99355", "Peak99674"), class = "factor"), 
    log2FoldChange_Region = c(-6.34669248759273, -3.48228412439449, 
    2.00811698735437, 2.00811698735437, 2.43720241001405, -2.43644562364537
    ), Family = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("EF", 
    "TF"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

My second dataframe that contains information which i want to map if the genes which are all related to haematopoesis.

```
dput(head(haematopoetic_genes))
structure(list(Rank = 1:6, Symbol = structure(c(134L, 209L, 138L, 
716L, 162L, 531L), .Label = c("18S_RRNA", "ABCA1", "ABCB1", "ABCG1", 
"ABCG2", "ABL1", "ACAN", "ACE", "ACHE", "ACKR2", "ACP5", "ACTG1", 
"ADA", "ADAMTS13", "ADIPOQ", "ADRB2", "AFDN", "AFF1", "AFP", 
"AGO2", "AICDA", "AIF1", "AIRE", "AKT1", "ALB", "ALCAM", "ALDH1A1", 
"ALK", "AMBP", "ANGPT1", "ANGPT2", "ANGPTL5", "ANPEP", "ANXA2", 
"ANXA5", "ANXA8", "AOC3", "APOA1", "APOE", "APP", "AR", "ARG1", 
"ARG2", "ARID3A", "ASXL1", "ATG5", "ATG7", "ATM", "ATP12A", "ATP4A", 
"AURKA", "AXIN1", "AXIN2", "AXL", "B3GAT1", "BANF1", "BCL11A", 
"BCL11B", "BCL2A1", "BCL2L1", "BCL2L11", "BCL6", "BCR", "BDNF", 
"BECN1", "BGLAP", "BLNK", "BMI1", "BMP2", "BMP4", "BMP6", "BMP7", 
"BRCA1", "BRCA2", "BRD4", "BTK", "C3", "CALCA", "CALR", "CASP1", 
"CASP3", "CASP8", "CASP9", "CBFA2T3", "CBL", "CCL11", "CCL17", 
"CCL19", "CCL2", "CCL20", "CCL21", "CCL25", "CCL27", "CCL3", 
"CCL4", "CCL4L2", "CCL5", "CCL7", "CCN2", "CCNA2", "CCNB1", "CCND1", 
"CCND2", "CCND3", "CCR1", "CCR2", "CCR3", "CCR5", "CCR6", "CCR7", 
"CCR9", "CCRL2", "CD163", "CD164", "CD19", "CD1A", "CD1B", "CD1C", 
"CD1D", "CD1E", "CD2", "CD200", "CD207", "CD22", "CD226", "CD24", 
"CD244", "CD247", "CD27", "CD274", "CD276", "CD28", "CD33", "CD34", 
"CD38", "CD3D", "CD3E", "CD4", "CD40", "CD40LG", "CD44", "CD47", 
"CD48", "CD5", "CD52", "CD55", "CD58", "CD59", "CD6", "CD63", 
"CD68", "CD69", "CD7", "CD70", "CD74", "CD79A", "CD79B", "CD80", 
"CD81", "CD83", "CD86", "CD8A", "CD9", "CD93", "CD96", "CDC42", 
"CDH1", "CDH17", "CDH2", "CDH5", "CDK1", "CDK2", "CDK4", "CDK6", 
"CDKN1A", "CDKN1B", "CDKN1C", "CDKN2A", "CDKN2B", "CDKN2C", "CDKN3", 
"CDX4", "CEACAM8", "CEBPA", "CEBPB", "CEBPE", "CFLAR", "CHEK1", 
"CHEK2", "CISH", "CLEC11A", "CLEC12A", "CLEC4C", "CLEC7A", "COL1A1", 
"COLEC10", "COMMD3-BMI1", "CR2", "CREB1", "CREBBP", "CRKL", "CRP", 
"CRYGC", "CSF1", "CSF1R", "CSF2", "CSF2RA", "CSF2RB", "CSF3", 
"CSF3R", "CTCF", "CTNNB1", "CTRL", "CTSG", "CTSK", "CX3CL1", 
"CX3CR1", "CXCL1", "CXCL10", "CXCL11", "CXCL12", "CXCL13", "CXCL2", 
"CXCL5", "CXCL8", "CXCL9", "CXCR1", "CXCR2", "CXCR3", "CXCR4", 
"CXCR5", "CYBB", "CYCS", "CYGB", "CYP3A4", "DCLRE1C", "DDX58", 
"DHFR", "DICER1", "DKC1", "DKK1", "DLK1", "DLL1", "DLL4", "DNMT1", 
"DNMT3A", "DNMT3B", "DNTT", "DOCK8", "DOT1L", "DPP4", "DROSHA", 
"DTX1", "EBF1", "EDN1", "EGF", "EGFR", "EGR1", "EGR2", "EIF2AK3", 
"EIF4EBP1", "ELANE", "ELN", "EMCN", "ENG", "ENO2", "ENSP00000204615", 
"ENSP00000217964", "ENSP00000228280", "ENSP00000245323", "ENSP00000268035", 
"ENSP00000277541", "ENSP00000282030", "ENSP00000303939", "ENSP00000332369", 
"ENSP00000344192", "ENSP00000349960", "ENSP00000350052", "ENSP00000352561", 
"ENSP00000356946", "ENSP00000387760", "ENSP00000433642", "ENSP00000444986", 
"ENSP00000452780", "ENSP00000478570", "ENSP00000479618", "ENSP00000480609", 
"ENTPD1", "EOMES", "EP300", "EPB41", "EPCAM", "EPO", "EPOR", 
"ERBB2", "ERVW-1", "ESAM", "ESR1", "ETS1", "ETS2", "ETV2", "ETV6", 
"EVPL", "EZH2", "F2", "F3", "FABP4", "FANCA", "FANCC", "FANCD2", 
"FANCG", "FAS", "FASLG", "FBXW7", "FCGR1A", "FCGR2A", "FCGR2B", 
"FER", "FGF1", "FGF13", "FGF2", "FGF4", "FGF7", "FGFR1", "FLT1", 
"FLT3", "FLT3LG", "FLT4", "FN1", "FOS", "FOSB", "FOXA2", "FOXN1", 
"FOXO1", "FOXO3", "FOXO4", "FOXP3", "FUT4", "FYN", "GADD45A", 
"GAPDH", "GAS6", "GATA1", "GATA2", "GATA3", "GATA4", "GCG", "GDNF", 
"GFAP", "GFI1", "GFI1B", "GJA1", "GLI1", "GLI3", "GP1BA", "GP9", 
"GPT", "GRB2", "GSTM1", "GUSB", "GYPA", "GYPC", "GZMB", "H2AC18", 
"H2AC19", "H2AC20", "H2AX", "H2BC21", "H3-2", "H4-16", "H4C1", 
"H4C11", "H4C12", "H4C13", "H4C14", "H4C15", "H4C2", "H4C3", 
"H4C4", "H4C5", "H4C6", "H4C8", "H4C9", "HAMP", "HAVCR2", "HBB", 
"HBE1", "HBEGF", "HBZ", "HDAC1", "HDAC2", "HEY1", "HEY2", "HGF", 
"HHEX", "HIF1A", "HLA-A", "HLA-B", "HLA-C", "HLA-DPB1", "HLA-DQA1", 
"HLA-DQB1", "HLA-DRB1", "HLA-E", "HLA-G", "HMGA2", "HMGB1", "HMOX1", 
"HNF4A", "HOXA10", "HOXA3", "HOXA5", "HOXA7", "HOXA9", "HOXB3", 
"HOXB4", "HOXB5", "HOXB6", "HOXB8", "HP", "HPGDS", "HPRT1", "HRAS", 
"HSA-MIR-125B-5P", "HSA-MIR-126-3P", "HSA-MIR-142-3P", "HSA-MIR-146A-5P", 
"HSA-MIR-150-5P", "HSA-MIR-155-5P", "HSA-MIR-17-5P", "HSA-MIR-181A-5P", 
"HSA-MIR-21-5P", "HSA-MIR-221-3P", "HSA-MIR-223-3P", "HSA-MIR-29A-3P", 
"HSA-MIR-34A-5P", "HSP90AA1", "HSPA4", "IBSP", "ICAM1", "ICAM4", 
"ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "IDH1", "IDH2", "IDO1", "IDUA", "IFNA1", 
"IFNA2", "IFNAR1", "IFNB1", "IFNG", "IGF1", "IGF2", "IGFBP2", 
"IGFBP3", "IGLL1", "IGLL5", "IHH", "IKBKB", "IKBKG", "IKZF1", 
"IKZF2", "IKZF3", "IL10", "IL10RA", "IL11", "IL13", "IL15", "IL17F", 
"IL18", "IL1A", "IL1B", "IL1R1", "IL2", "IL22", "IL2RA", "IL2RB", 
"IL2RG", "IL3", "IL33", "IL3RA", "IL4", "IL5", "IL6", "IL6R", 
"IL7", "IL7R", "IL9", "INS", "IRAK1", "IRF1", "IRF2", "IRF4", 
"IRF7", "IRF8", "IRS1", "ITGA2", "ITGA2B", "ITGA4", "ITGA5", 
"ITGA6", "ITGAE", "ITGAL", "ITGAM", "ITGAV", "ITGAX", "ITGB1", 
"ITGB2", "ITGB3", "ITIH4", "ITK", "JAG1", "JAG2", "JAK1", "JAK2", 
"JAK3", "JUN", "KAT6A", "KCNN3", "KDM1A", "KDM6A", "KDR", "KIR2DL1", 
"KIR2DL3", "KIR2DL4", "KIR3DL1", "KIR3DL2", "KIR3DL3", "KIT", 
"KLF1", "KLF2", "KLF4", "KLRB1", "KLRC1", "KLRC2", "KLRD1", "KLRG1", 
"KLRK1", "KMT2A", "KRAS", "KRT14", "KRT18", "KRT19", "KRT5", 
"KRT8", "LAG3", "LAMP1", "LCK", "LCN2", "LCP2", "LDB1", "LDB2", 
"LEF1", "LEP", "LEPR", "LGALS3", "LGALS4", "LGR5", "LIF", "LIG4", 
"LILRB1", "LIN28A", "LIN28B", "LMNA", "LMO2", "LOX", "LRP5", 
"LTA", "LY75", "LY9", "LYL1", "LYN", "LYVE1", "MAF", "MAGEA3", 
"MAP2K1", "MAP2K7", "MAPK1", "MAPK14", "MAPK3", "MAPK8", "MATK", 
"MBP", "MCAM", "MCL1", "MDM2", "MECOM", "MEF2C", "MEIS1", "MET", 
"MGMT", "MICA", "MIR17HG", "MIXL1", "MLLT1", "MLLT10", "MLLT3", 
"MME", "MMP2", "MMP3", "MMP9", "MOG", "MPL", "MPO", "MPP3", "MRC1", 
"MSI2", "MTHFR", "MTOR", "MUC1", "MX1", "MYB", "MYCN", "MYD88", 
"MYH11", "MYO1G", "MYOD1", "MYOM2", "NAALADL1", "NANOG", "NCAM1", 
"NCF1", "NCOR1", "NCOR2", "NCR1", "NCR2", "NCR3", "NES", "NF1", 
"NFATC1", "NFE2", "NFIL3", "NFKB1", "NFKBIA", "NGF", "NGFR", 
"NKX2-5", "NLRP3", "NOD2", "NOG", "NOS2", "NOS3", "NOTCH2", "NOTCH3", 
"NOTCH4", "NPM1", "NR3C1", "NR4A1", "NRAS", "NRP1", "NT5E", "NTRK1", 
"NUMB", "NUP98", "OSM", "PARP1", "PAX5", "PAX6", "PBX1", "PCGF2", 
"PCSK5", "PCSK7", "PDCD1", "PDCD1LG2", "PDGFRA", "PDGFRB", "PDPN", 
"PECAM1", "PF4", "PGF", "PGK1", "PHF6", "PI3", "PIGA", "PIK3R1", 
"PLAUR", "PLCG1", "PLCG2", "PLEK", "PLG", "PLK1", "PMAIP1", "POMC", 
"POU5F1", "PPARA", "PPARG", "PPARGC1A", "PPBP", "PPIG", "PPP1R12C", 
"PRAME", "PRDM1", "PRDM16", "PREB", "PRF1", "PRKCA", "PRKDC", 
"PRL", "PROCR", "PROM1", "PRTN3", "PSMA7", "PTCRA", "PTEN", "PTGER4", 
"PTGS2", "PTH", "PTHLH", "PTK2", "PTK2B", "PTN", "PTPN11", "PTPN6", 
"PTPRC", "QRSL1", "RAC2", "RAD21", "RAD51", "RAF1", "RAG1", "RAG2", 
"RARA", "RBFOX3", "RBPJ", "REG3A", "REL", "RELA", "RELB", "REN", 
"RET", "RGMA", "RHOA", "RICTOR", "RORC", "RPS14", "RPS19", "RPS6", 
"RPS6KB1", "RPTOR", "RUNX1", "RUNX1T1", "RUNX2", "RUNX3", "S1PR1", 
"SAA1", "SALL4", "SATB1", "SBDS", "SDC1", "SDHC", "SELE", "SELL", 
"SELP", "SELPLG", "SERPINA1", "SERPINC1", "SERPINE1", "SH2B3", 
"SHC1", "SHH", "SHMT2", "SIGLEC1", "SIRPA", "SIRT1", "SIRT3", 
"SIRT7", "SLAMF1", "SLC2A1", "SMAD2", "SMAD3", "SMAD4", "SMAD5", 
"SMAD7", "SMARCA4", "SNAI1", "SNAI2", "SOCS1", "SOCS2", "SOCS3", 
"SOD2", "SOX17", "SOX2", "SOX4", "SOX9", "SP7", "SPARC", "SPI1", 
"SPIB", "SPN", "SPP1", "SRC", "SRSF2", "STAG2", "STAT1", "STAT2", 
"STAT3", "STAT5A", "STAT5B", "STAT6", "STK11", "STUB1", "SUZ12", 
"SYK", "TAC1", "TAL1", "TBP", "TBX21", "TCF12", "TCF3", "TCF4", 
"TCF7", "TCHP", "TEK", "TERC", "TERT", "TET1", "TET2", "TFRC", 
"TGFB1", "TGFB2", "TGFB3", "TGFBR1", "TGFBR2", "TH", "THBD", 
"THBS1", "THRA", "THY1", "TIE1", "TIMP1", "TJP1", "TLR1", "TLR2", 
"TLR3", "TLR4", "TLR5", "TLR7", "TLR8", "TLR9", "TLX1", "TNF", 
"TNFRSF10A", "TNFRSF10B", "TNFRSF13C", "TNFRSF18", "TNFRSF1A", 
"TNFRSF1B", "TNFRSF25", "TNFRSF4", "TNFRSF8", "TNFRSF9", "TNFSF10", 
"TNFSF11", "TNFSF13B", "TNFSF4", "TNFSF9", "TOP1", "TP53", "TP53BP1", 
"TRAF6", "TRIM5", "TSLP", "TTR", "TXN", "TYK2", "TYROBP", "U2AF1", 
"U2AF1L4", "U2AF1L5", "UBC", "UCHL1", "UNC13D", "VAV1", "VCAM1", 
"VEGFC", "VPREB1", "VTN", "VWF", "WAS", "WNT1", "WNT10B", "WNT16", 
"WNT3A", "WNT4", "WNT5A", "WT1", "XBP1", "XIAP", "XRCC5", "XRCC6", 
"YY1", "ZAP70", "ZBTB16", "ZBTB7B", "ZEB1", "ZFPM1", "ZRSR2"), class = "factor"), 
    Publication.count = c(18386L, 7830L, 6786L, 6590L, 6022L, 
    5610L), Fraction.of.publications.from.total.gene.publication = c(0.2923, 
    0.2598, 0.029, 0.1107, 0.0383, 0.1407)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

The dimension of my first dataframe

```
dim(EF_TF_region_expression)
[1] 80  8
```

The dimension of my second dataframe

```
dim(haematopoetic_genes)
[1] 899   4
>
```

If i do an inner_join

```
haem_non_haem = inner_join(EF_TF_region_expression,haematopoetic_genes)
```

I get this dimension

dim(haem_non_haem)
[1] 17 11

So here I loose rest of the rows which didn't map to my second dataframe. I would like to keep all the rows with some label such as `"Non-haem"`

I tried full_join

```
haem_non_haem1 = full_join(EF_TF_region_expression,haematopoetic_genes,by ="Symbol")
```

My dimension is this

dim(haem_non_haem1)
[1] 964  11

So here Im getting more rows from second dataframe which i dont want.

The final output im expecting is I would keep all my 80 rows instead of 17 which are mapped and which are not mapped should be put some label

```
ENSEMBL Symbol      gene      Region log2FoldChange_gene Peak_Region log2FoldChange_Region Family
1 ENSG00000030419  IKZF2 gene_down Region_down           -2.662778  Peak116875             -3.482284     TF
2 ENSG00000057657  PRDM1   gene_UP   Region_UP            3.888709  Peak182835              2.008117     EF
3 ENSG00000057657  PRDM1   gene_UP   Region_UP            3.888709  Peak182835              2.008117     TF
4 ENSG00000085276  MECOM gene_down Region_down           -8.786649  Peak144690             -5.930731     TF
5 ENSG00000091831   ESR1 gene_down Region_down           -1.884222  Peak187290             -2.431486     TF
6 ENSG00000107485  GATA3 gene_down Region_down           -8.905856   Peak21185             -4.434688     TF
  Rank Publication.count Fraction.of.publications.from.total.gene.publication
1  895                36                                               0.0845
2  496               105                                               0.0266
3  496               105                                               0.0266
4  317               178                                               0.1803
5  193               323                                               0.0049
6  140               465                                               0.0404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you want join normally and do `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(EF_TF_region_expression,haematopoetic_genes) %>% 
  mutate(some_new_label = ifelse(is.na(Rank),"Non-haem","Haem"))
```